# JMeter: How to set content to the request of a Java Request Sample on "View Results Tree" page?

Tags: jmeter, viewresult

I created a test plan with JMeter, and this plan include a Thread Group which contains 2 Java Request Sample. The plan runs successfully. But when I open the "View Results Tree", and select the "Request" tab for a Java request, there is "no data to display".

I want to display a string here, and I did set the string to SampleResult by:

*sampleResult.setRequestHeader(requestString);*

However, setting request header seems not to work.

What should I do to display the string in "Request" tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should 1st choose under `classname` dropdown menu value `org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.test.JavaTest`

Then in the `Sampler data` field you should input your request data i.e `I requested this`.

And then when you look at the result from `View Results Tree` , when you click on your sampler `Request` tab there you'll see `I requested this` which you previously wrote.

[image]

@JuliaLi
Click on the check image on the left side of this answer.

Comment: What should I do to accept to answer? I never see an "accept" button on the page.

Comment: in java ,it's `sampleResult.setSamplerData( "your request data" );`